# Customize update entity on Spring Data repository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have `XRepository` interface (extends [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)). On create or update `X` entity i need to call method of another repository (`YRepository`) in transaction (exactly: update some field and use new value in created/updated entity `X`).

To do that i created a service class with `@Transactional` methods and custom REST Controller. POST mapping on controller works OK and is acceptable for me, but have problem how to implement in more elegant way update (PUT/PATCH) existing entity in my service layer. It works too, but had to use `BeanUtils.copyProperties()`. Is a better, more conventional way to do that ?

```
public interface XRepository extends JpaRepository<X, Long> {
}

public interface YRepository extends JpaRepository<Y, Long> {
}

@BasePathAwareController
public class XRestControllerCustom {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @PostMapping("/x")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<X> create(@RequestBody Resource<X> x) {     
        return new ResponseEntity<X>(myService.save(x.getContent()), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PatchMapping("/x/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<X> update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Resource<X> x) {
        myService.update(id, x.getContent());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}

@Component
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private XRepository xRepository;

    @Autowired
    private YRepository yRepository;

    @Transactional
    public X save(X x) {
        yRepository.update();
        x.setField(yRepository.get());
        return xRepository.save(x);
    }   

    @Transactional
    public X update(Long id, X partial) {
        X x = xRepository.getOne(id);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(x, partial);
        x.setId(id); // because copyProperties makes id null
        yRepository.update();
        x.setField(yRepository.get());
        return xRepository.save(x);     
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are X and Y related?

Comment: `X` and `Y` are not related.